# JAVA - ¿Un buen obsfucador?

Tags: java

Últimamente estaba probando ProGuard pero me tiraba un Byte Error, estoy buscando un obsfucador que no modifique tanto el código solamente los nombres de clases y objectos.

Comment: Hola Java doub. Este tipo de preguntas se basan mucho en las opiniones personales de las personas. Podrías editar la pregunta para preguntar sobre cómo resolver problemas particulares para un ofuscador de código, esas son aceptables en el sitio.